# Should file expansion happen before a command sees its argument?

Tags: bash, git

In Bash, given a command which takes a pathname as an argument, does file expansion happen to the pathname argument before the command can see the value of this argument?

My question comes from [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476787/are-git-commands-supposed-to-be-run-under-the-working-directory-directly/34478315?noredirect=1#comment56738633_34478315) about what does `.` refer to in the following git commands:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/my/repo/.git add .
git --work-tree=/a/path --git-dir=/path/to/my/repo/.git add .
git -C /path/to/my/repo add .
```

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34478315/156458) that my comment replies to and the following comments say that `.` doesn't always mean the directory where I run the command. But I don't understand it, because I think file expansion happens before the command can see the value of the argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*All* expansions take place before the command is run. How the command interprets what it gets is entirely up to it. None of your example commands have any expansions involved - `.` is not expanded by the shell.

The `git` command uses `.` *after* changing directories according to your options, so `.` won't be *your* current directory. Nor will `tar` archive my current directory in the following command:

```
tar -C etc -c .
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I might be mistaken. Is it correct that `.` is a hardlink, not glob subject to file expansion?

Comment: `.` is a hard link, and unless you are using some shell which supports global aliases, `.` isn't expanded, since none of the usual shell expansions apply to it. These two things are unrelated.

Comment: Ok. `.` a relative pathname without any shell expansions, and is what the command will see for the value of the argument.